# Use active kerberos session(s) for authentication in cntlm for Mac

Tags: kerberos

With the PassNTLMv2 configuration option one can pass authenticate to a corporate proxy.

Is it also possible to use kerberos credentials with CNTLM? Or is there a way to obtain the NTLMv2 password automatically from a Kerberos ticket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kerberos and NTLM have nothing in common. This won't work. NTLM requires the pw to be available to calculate the challenge while Kerberos relies on the TGT, i.e., the password can be thrown away as soon as you have the TGT.

Answer (score 2):

See [BPF](https://github.com/ecovaci/bpf)
It's something like CNTLM but for Kerberos proxy. Beside, it has a graphical interface.

Comment: Can this also work without configuring username and password and instead re-use the Kerberos Ticket managed by Nomad on Mac?

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen Yes, I suppose, but the source code must be modified accordingly.